# Dimension of $k[x_1,...,x_d]$ localized at arbitrary maximal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Atiyah-Macdonald's Introduction to Commutative Algebra, when proving the equivalence between the local dimension at any point of a variety and the dimension of the variety (Proposition 11.25), he uses the following fact: the dimension of $k[x_1,...,x_d]$ localized at any maximal ideal, i.e. $(x_1-a_1,...,x_d-a_d)$ is equal to $d$. The reason he gives is that **any point of affine space can be taken as the origin of coordinates**, so localizing $k[x_1,...,x_d]$ at any maximal ideal is the same as localizing at $(x_1,...,x_d)$, which gives dimension $d$. What I am confused is about the **bold** part. Since I am quite unfamiliar with affine space and most of the AG books define it simply as $k^n$, I only know the affine space is like a vector space without a fixed origin. Is there a formal way to explain why we can interpret the localization at any maximal ideal as localizing at $(x_1,...,x_d)$? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automorphism of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_d]$ given by $x_i\mapsto x_i+a_i$ sends the maximal ideal $(x_1-a_1,\cdots,x_d-a_d)$ to $(x_1,\cdots,x_d)$ and therefore gives an isomorphism between these localizations. (One should assume $k$ is algebraically closed in order that every maximal ideal is of the type listed.)